# error 501:Not implemented ,google-drive upload using qt

Tags: qt, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload file to google-drive.I have done authorizing part and got access tokens but I get error 501 not implemented while running my code.
My code for uploading: http://pastebin.com/Z9BKtPV9

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `Content-Range` header which is not supported. Please read the documentation on [uploading files with the Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads) to find out how to do it.

Comment: I tried to do as you told.Foll. is my code:http://pastebin.com/tyBK6RMt.But I get foll. error:http://pastebin.com/e5Y3yQDd.In authorization header I have added access token which I received on sending request.Foll was the response:http://pastebin.com/sZd2ut8f.Am I putting wrong token in authorization part? Ali Afshar